# How to add and subtract values from previous statements

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am getting the error invalid column name with the following code:

```
SELECT 
    DS, AccNumber, PPeriod, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1010000' THEN amount END) AS Opening, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1010000' THEN amount END) AS electricity,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1045000' THEN amount END) AS water, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1000000' THEN amount END) AS levy,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '2750000' THEN amount END) AS Interest, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '4000000' THEN amount END) AS Legal,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1020000' THEN amount END) AS Sewer,
    SUM(CASE WHEN LinkAcc IN ('4350003','3850000','9250000') THEN amount END) As Other,
    SUM(CASE WHEN LinkAcc IN ('8420000','8400000') AND amount < 0 THEN amount END) As Payments,
   (Opening + electricity + water + levy + Interest + Legal + Sewer + Other - Payments) AS Due
FROM 
    dbo.Table1
WHERE 
    (AccNumber BETWEEN 'CC001' AND 'CC100')
GROUP BY 
    DataSource, AccNumber, PPeriod
HAVING 
    (DataSource = 'PAS11CEDCRE16') AND (PPeriod = 112)
```

I am trying to do the above addition and subtraction and I get invalid column name, I tried putting the table name before the column name but it still failed.

Comment: Do you think you know which column is the issue?  Also what does your table look like?  could be a simple typo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use your current query as a derive table, or use a CTE.

Derived table:

```
SELECT  *,
        (Opening + electricity + water + levy + Interest + Legal + Sewer + Other - Payments) AS Due
FROM (  SELECT DS, AccNumber, PPeriod, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1010000' THEN amount END) AS Opening, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1010000' THEN amount END) AS electricity,
        MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1045000' THEN amount END) AS water, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1000000' THEN amount END) AS levy,
        MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '2750000' THEN amount END) AS Interest, 
        MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '4000000' THEN amount END) AS Legal,
        MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1020000' THEN amount END) AS Sewer,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LinkAcc IN ('4350003','3850000','9250000') THEN amount END) As Other,
        SUM(CASE WHEN LinkAcc IN ('8420000','8400000') AND amount < 0 THEN amount END) As Payments,
        FROM dbo.Table1
        WHERE (AccNumber BETWEEN 'CC001' AND 'CC100')
        GROUP BY DataSource, AccNumber, PPeriod
        HAVING (DataSource = 'PAS11CEDCRE16') AND (PPeriod = 112)) AS T;
```

CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT DS, AccNumber, PPeriod, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1010000' THEN amount END) AS Opening, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1010000' THEN amount END) AS electricity,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1045000' THEN amount END) AS water, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1000000' THEN amount END) AS levy,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '2750000' THEN amount END) AS Interest, 
    MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '4000000' THEN amount END) AS Legal,
    MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1020000' THEN amount END) AS Sewer,
    SUM(CASE WHEN LinkAcc IN ('4350003','3850000','9250000') THEN amount END) As Other,
    SUM(CASE WHEN LinkAcc IN ('8420000','8400000') AND amount < 0 THEN amount END) As Payments,
    FROM dbo.Table1
    WHERE (AccNumber BETWEEN 'CC001' AND 'CC100')
    GROUP BY DataSource, AccNumber, PPeriod
    HAVING (DataSource = 'PAS11CEDCRE16') AND (PPeriod = 112)
)
SELECT  *,
        (Opening + electricity + water + levy + Interest + Legal + Sewer + Other - Payments) AS Due
FROM CTE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using CTE

```
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT DS, AccNumber, PPeriod, 
MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1010000' THEN amount END) AS Opening, 
MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1010000' THEN amount END) AS electricity,
MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1045000' THEN amount END) AS water, 
MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1000000' THEN amount END) AS levy,
MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '2750000' THEN amount END) AS Interest, 
MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '4000000' THEN amount END) AS Legal,
MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1020000' THEN amount END) AS Sewer,
SUM(CASE WHEN LinkAcc IN ('4350003','3850000','9250000') THEN amount END) As Other,
SUM(CASE WHEN LinkAcc IN ('8420000','8400000') AND amount < 0 THEN amount END) As Payments

FROM dbo.Table1
WHERE (AccNumber BETWEEN 'CC001' AND 'CC100')
GROUP BY DataSource, AccNumber, PPeriod,

HAVING (DataSource = 'PAS11CEDCRE16') AND (PPeriod = 112))

Select 
*,
(Opening + electricity + water + levy + Interest + Legal + Sewer + Other - Payments) AS Due 
FROM
     CTE
```

OR

Derived table :

```
Select T.*,
(Opening + electricity + water + levy + Interest + Legal + Sewer + Other - Payments) AS Due  from (
SELECT DS, AccNumber, PPeriod, 
MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1010000' THEN amount END) AS Opening, 
MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1010000' THEN amount END) AS electricity,
MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1045000' THEN amount END) AS water, 
MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1000000' THEN amount END) AS levy,
MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '2750000' THEN amount END) AS Interest, 
MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '4000000' THEN amount END) AS Legal,
MAX(CASE WHEN LinkAcc = '1020000' THEN amount END) AS Sewer,
SUM(CASE WHEN LinkAcc IN ('4350003','3850000','9250000') THEN amount END) As Other,
SUM(CASE WHEN LinkAcc IN ('8420000','8400000') AND amount < 0 THEN amount END) As Payments

FROM dbo.Table1
WHERE (AccNumber BETWEEN 'CC001' AND 'CC100')
GROUP BY DataSource, AccNumber, PPeriod,

HAVING (DataSource = 'PAS11CEDCRE16') AND (PPeriod = 112))T
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the query with outer SELECT. You can not introduce an alias and use it in the same SELECT clause.

```
SELECT Opening, 
  electricity,
  water, 
  levy,
  Interest, 
  Legal,
  Sewer,
  Other,
  Payments,
  (Opening + electricity + water + levy + Interest + Legal + Sewer + Other - Payments) AS Due
FROM (
-- original query here
) q
```